# ProgressDialog cannot stop when load JSON

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, spinner, progressdialog

please help, I've given up on finding a solution
Data json already be in ArrayList, nothing error found but the progressdialog can't stop loading. I'm already put PG.dismis in postExecute but even the Adapter cannot changed.

```
private static List<DataVoucher> processResponse(String response) {
    List<DataVoucher> list = new ArrayList<DataVoucher>();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("produk");
        Log.d(TAG, "data lengt: " + jsonArray.length());
        DataVoucher dataVoucher = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            dataVoucher = new DataVoucher();
            dataVoucher.setKode(obj.getString("kode"));
            dataVoucher.setHrg(obj.getString("hrg"));
            dataVoucher.setNom(obj.getString("nom"));
            dataVoucher.setKet(obj.getString("ket"));
            list.add(dataVoucher);

            listvoucher.add(obj.getString("nom"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    return list;
}

public static String requestDataVoucher(final String operator) {
    final String TAG = "SEND JSON";
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            JSONObject jsonObjSend = new JSONObject();

            try {
                jsonObjSend.put("type", "svoc");
                jsonObjSend.put("hp", "089631633614");
                jsonObjSend.put("opr", operator);

                Log.i(TAG, jsonObjSend.toString(2));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            SendHttpPost(jsonObjSend);
            Looper.loop();
        }
    };
    thread.start();
    return TAG;
}

private class MainActivityAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("retrieving...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String response = requestDataVoucher(pilihOperator
                .getSelectedItem().toString());
        list = processResponse(response);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listvoucher);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        pilihVoucher.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        if (!adapter.isEmpty()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        } // this is annoying
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listvoucher);

I think u mean 
  adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

Btw just dismiss ur progressDialog at onPostExecute() not checking anything  and maybe warn the user if the list is empty so you will evade these problems.

Comment: if dismiss put in postexecude then adapter spinner pilihvoucher nothing changed

Comment: if (!adapter.isEmpty()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }  ---> progressDialog.dismiss(); 
If u cannot see any data then maybe the list is empty. Debug it

Answer (score 0):

Many issues here

- `doInBackground` is running in a thread, different from the ui thread. You are calling `requestDataVoucher` which is also creating a new thread, useless in this case.
- You are calling `processResponse` with the String `response` which is the result of `requestDataVoucher`. According to your code, `response` equals `"SEND JSON"`. So `JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);` will trigger an Exception, listvoucher will remain empty, and so will your adapter. Conclusion, adapter is empty, the `progressDialog` won't disappear.

I can't propose a fix, as `SendHttpPost` is unknown. But as far as goes my understanding, you should remove the Thread creation from `requestDataVoucher` and return the JSON String generate by `SendHttpPost`.